# Firefox extension to close firefox window

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm developing a firefox extension and i want to be able to close firefox window itself (without any confirm). For example, I want to close firefox window if a specific URL has been loaded. Open/close tab is easy with gBrowser, what about closing firefox window?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## To quit Firefox

```
Components
  .classes['@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1']
  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAppStartup)
  .quit(Components.interfaces.nsIAppStartup.eAttemptQuit)
```

## To restart Firefox

```
var boot = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAppStartup);
boot.quit(Components.interfaces.nsIAppStartup.eForceQuit|Components.interfaces.nsIAppStartup.eRestart);
```

## Additional Useful Flags

**eConsiderQuit** : Attempt to quit if all windows are closed.
**eAttemptQuit** : Try to close all windows, then quit if successful.
**eForceQuit** : Force all windows to close, then quit.
**eRestart** : Restart the application after quitting. The application will be restarted with the same profile and an empty command line.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds obvious but you use [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close) to close a XUL window. As to the warning, the best way is probably to temporarily switch the `browser.tabs.warnOnClose` preference to `false`. Something like this should work:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var prefName = "browser.tabs.warnOnClose";
var restorePref = false;
if (Services.prefs.getBoolPref(prefName))
{
  Services.prefs.setBoolPref(prefName, false);
  restorePref = true;
}

window.close();

if (restorePref)
  Services.prefs.setBoolPref(prefName, true);
```